# In Polymer 1.0 how can I databind to a boolean property of an element?

Tags: polymer

How can I bind to a boolean property of an element. It seems this

```
<my-element a-property-of-type-boolean='{{someBoolean}}'></my-element>
```

does not Work, but I also cant find out how to bind to it when it is exposed like this:

```
<my-element a-property-of-type-boolean></my-element>
```

It seems an option is to set the type to Object instead of Boolean, but I am not sure how valid this approach is

Thanks :-)

Comment: Did @Granze answer your question? If not, could you please include all the code of your `<my-element>` element? To get an idea of, specifically, how you want the binding to occur? Particularly, what's going on in the `<script>` section and how it interacts with the `<template>`?

Answer (score 4):

If you put an attribute on your element, the related property it will always be true. For example in:

```
<my-element a-property-of-type-boolean='false'></my-element>
```

`a-property-of-type-boolean` is true.

So, if you you want to use a Boolean property on your element, I suggest to declare the property with the default value of false and then, if you need to change the value to true, you can add the attribute on you element.

Your Polymer prototype:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'my-element',
  properties: {
    aPropertyOfTypeBoolean: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: false
    }
  }
});
```

Your element:

```
<my-element a-property-of-type-boolean></my-element>
```

Comment: I don't think this is true?  Or at least not relevant.  The question was about property binding; the example here doesn't bind any properties, just a terminal value of false.  In any event, @franz-thomsen is correct with his example, and property binding with boolean values work as expected.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, just point out a difficulty in the problem.

Comment: This does not answer how to bind a property to a boolean attribute.

Answer (score 2):

As you already figured it out, the behavior of boolean properties has changed in Polymer 1.0 ([ref](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#attribute-deserialization)) and now follows the specification of HTML boolean attributes.

You got different solutions to this, but until now I haven't found a clean solution.

As a preface of the solution I'll make a tiny improvement (adding an Id to the problematic element) to your code:

```
<dom-module id='main-page'>
    <template>
        <paper-button on-tap='tap'>Click me</paper-button>
        <my-element id="myElem" a-property-of-type-boolean></my-element>
        <div>In main page it is <div>{{someBoolean}}</div></div>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

1. ([ref](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#notify)) You could listen to  notification's and manually add and remove the attribute from your element ([ref](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#dom-api)).

   ```
   tap: function() {
     if (this.aPropertyOfTypeBoolean) {
       Polymer.dom(this.$.myElem).removeAttribute('aPropertyOfTypeBoolean');
     } else {
       Polymer.dom(this.$.myElem).setAttribute('aPropertyOfTypeBoolean', true);
     }
   }
   ```
2. If you edit the  to use a Boolean attribute you can also set it's property as follows: (it wont reflect in the html unless you use `reflectToAttribute: true` in the property being defined as Boolean):.

   ```
   tap: function() {
     this.$.myElem.set('aPropertyOfTypeBoolean', Boolean(this.aPropertyOfTypeBoolean));
   }
   ```
3. Or you can either hide your element with hidden or **template-if** solutions.

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{someBoolean}}">
    <my-element a-property-of-type-boolean></my-element>
</template>

<template is="dom-if" if="{{!someBoolean}}">
    <my-element></my-element>
</template>
```

1. With **hidden**

```
<my-element hidden$="{{someBoolean}}"></my-element>
<my-element a-property-of-type-boolean hidden$="{{!someBoolean}}"></my-element>
```

Comment: I'm really sorry about the formatting, web editors are my worst tools

Answer (score 1):

Ok, sorry about that guys. I have not done my homework. Everything actually seems to be working exactly as I was hoping for and databinding Works fine. Here is the small example that I did to try and prove my point

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0'>
  <meta name='mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes'>
  <meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes'>

  <script src='bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js'></script>
  <link rel='import' href='bower_components/polymer/polymer.html'>
</head>
<body>
<dom-module id='my-element'>
    <template>
        <div>In my element it is <div>{{aPropertyOfTypeBoolean}}</div></div>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-element',

        properties: {
            aPropertyOfTypeBoolean: {
                type: Boolean,
                value: false,
            }
        }
    });
</script>                               

<dom-module id='main-page'>
    <template>
        <paper-button on-tap='tap'>Click me</paper-button>
        <my-element a-property-of-type-boolean='{{someBoolean}}'></my-element>
        <div>In main page it is <div>{{someBoolean}}</div></div>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'main-page',

        properties: {
            someBoolean: {
                type: Boolean,
                value: false
            }
        },

        tap: function(){
            this.someBoolean = !this.someBoolean;
        }
    });
</script>

<main-page></main-page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add $ at the end of it:

```
<my-element a-property-of-type-boolean$='[[someBoolean]]'></my-element>
```

The `$` makes it set an attribute (instead of a JS property), and in the case of a boolean (which the docs conveniently doesn't mention) it adds the attribute if `someBoolean` is `true`, otherwise removes the attribute if `someBoolean` is `false`.

Note, `{{}}` is for two-way bindings and the docs [do state](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#attribute-binding) that

> Attribute bindings are always one-way, host-to-target.

. Thus `a-property-of-type-boolean$='{{someBoolean}}'` works the same, but may be confusing because it is not two-way, so using `[[]]` is nicer.